# jquery 2.0.3 not working with IE

Tags: jquery

I have the following sample html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Example</title>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.7.js"></script>-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#mainheader').css("color", "red");
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="mainheader" class="header">Sample 1</h1>
    <h2 class="header info">Sample 2</h2>
    <h3 class="info">Sample 3</h3>
</body>
</html>
```

When i run the same with jQuery version 2.0.3, it runs into error:

Unhandled exception at line 834, column 4 in /Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.js

0x800a01b6 - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method

At the line:
// Use the handy event callback
document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", completed, false );

But if I run with a lower version of it i.e., 1.7, it works fine...

However the above code works perfectly fine for both versions on Chrome.

Can you please help me out with the differences:

Thanks & Regards.

Comment: **jQuery 2.x has the same API as jQuery 1.x, but does not support Internet Explorer 6, 7, or 8.**

Comment: i am seeing same error with jquery 2.2.0 in IE 11, how to rectify it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

At the moment jQuery 2.x " does not support Internet Explorer 6, 7, or 8"

From http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/:

Comment: and let us all rejoice. I'm waiting for the official departure of XP to make to move in dropping support for IE 8. But its coming so quick. Now, to work on the woman in the office who refers to IE9 by simply "her favorite browser"

Comment: i am seeing same error with jquery 2.2.0 in IE 11, how to rectify it?

Answer (score 5):

Since no one's mentioned it (and it was called out in the comments), here's another possible way of resolving this. This is actually how I'd recommend you roll out your compatibility failsafe, and how I perform it on my projects.

As many have already mentioned, jQuery 2.x drops support for IE8 and below ([with a lot of the major changes stemming back from 1.9 even](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#overview)). The reason for the drop being the goal of a smaller overall file size, and faster performance.

That being said, the ideal goal for an application would be to use jQuery 2.x for supported browsers, while offering compatibility for browsers that aren't.

So what I recommend is to just use the jQuery 2.x file (that's what you're supposed to be using anyway, if you're thinking about the future for your application). Not much needed here; just add in your jQuery as before.

```
<!-- according to h5bp -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

Then, to ensure compatibility with older IE versions, you can conditionally include the [patch file](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/#readme) so that it's processed when necessary.

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

This ensures you've got a faster, leaner jQuery for supported browsers, and a *working* jQuery for others, at the cost of what essentially equates to an extra HTTP call (and potentially a larger total bandwidth payload) for when you need the patch.

Comment: jQuery Migrate is just a shim for functionality that was removed in jQuery 1.9. It does not return old IE support to jQuery 2.0. jQuery 1.9 still supports old IEs.

Comment: i am seeing same error with jquery 2.2.0 in IE 11, how to rectify it??

Answer (score 2):

[From the site](http://jquery.com/download/) :

> jQuery 2.x has the same API as jQuery 1.x, but does not support
>   Internet Explorer 6, 7, or 8.

Use the 1.x versions if you need to be compatible with old IE browsers (or recent ones in compatibility mode). The 2.x versions are a branch which removed a lot of stuff whose sole usage was compatibility with those old browsers.

Comment: i am seeing same error with jquery 2.2.0 in IE 11, how to rectify it?

Answer (score 2):

Thats because of the version 2.0.3 does not support IE8 and 1.7 does

Answer (score 2):

jQuery 2+ version does not support IE < 9, if you are planning to support those browsers please stick to the latest 1.x branch version - now 1.10.2

Comment: or slap on the jQuery patch file.

Comment: @RichardNeilIlagan this sounds like the best answer and offers something the other answer don't. I am not familiar with the patch for 2.x why use it over 1.x when you need to include support for ie 7 or 8?

Comment: @matchew ~ jQuery 2.x is smaller and arguably faster than previous versions, because it doesn't try to work around and be friendly with IE8 below. The result is leaner code which doesn't have too much reason to work around frustrating "bugs". Using the patch / migration file allows you to (1) use the 2.x version for browsers that support it, while (2) providing compatibility for older browsers, at (3) the expense of an extra HTTP request + possibly larger total payload for when you need the patch file.

Comment: @RichardNeilIlagan - That makes a lot of sense. I was aware of the improvements, but wondered why a patch. Wouldn't that just be self defeating, why not stay with 1.x, but it does make sense. Only the old browsers would be aware of the patch and the new browsers can just continue to hum along. Now I have to reevaluate my decision not to move to 2.x, thanks (more work :)

Comment: i am seeing same error with jquery 2.2.0 in IE 11, how to rectify it?

Answer (score 0):

For IE 11 you must have the following in your HTML page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
           <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge;" />
```

If you have the old html 4.01 doctype tag, it doesn't work.